# SSRS report viewer did not show export tab

Tags: c#, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a report with ssrs, I have installed report viewer for mvc. It works fine but I cannot find the export tabs in report
[image]

[image]

The first is the image that does not have the export tab whilethe second image is the previous project which I did having the export tab. Please any solution will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at your reportserver config file to ensure the other required extensions / renders are enabled? File name is rsreportserver.config you can usually find it on your reportserver in the following location : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRSXX_XX.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer 

The XX depends on the version you have

Comment: sorry if I do not understand question correctly, but does PDF, Word option not export the data?? isn't that the export options in SSRS

Comment: @harry thanks I will try that and give feedback

Comment: @ankuser the export options are not in the report viewer... but the pic I attached with the export option was a project I did previously that has it

Comment: I ve been able to resolve it,the problem was the size of the report (.rdlc) , increasing the size made all options visible

Answer (score 0):

You must add **ShowExportControls="True"**    in the report viewer tag, like this

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"  
      ShowToolBar="True" ShowExportControls="True" ShowPrintButton="True">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

[image]